# What's the meaning of "spit" in "my own spit and faith"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature, paraprosdokian

What's the meaning of "spit" in the following statement?

> I believe in a good laugh, a day's fishing, a bit of gardening. I was very proud of my old greenhouse, made out of my own **spit** and faith. That’s the sort of man I am. Not size but quality.

Source: *[The Birthday Party](https://books.google.it/books?id=vLY_ZG5ZPr4C&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22my%20old%20greenhouse%20made%20out%20of%20my%20own%20spit%20and%20faith%22&source=bl&ots=0K6QxlPX4v&sig=IxAfPLRFs-gnSzdGtY3sTJYVvX8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1h4u9zMrXAhVCuBQKHaBuAYUQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22my%20old%20greenhouse%20made%20out%20of%20my%20own%20spit%20and%20faith%22&f=false)* (1961), written by Harold Pinter

Does it mean the same as "saliva"? If yes, what is it to do with "faith"?

Answer (score 2):

"Spit and faith" means hard (or careful) work and self-belief. Compare with "spit and polish" (although *spit* can mean *saliva* here, since it was once a common way of cleaning one's shoes quickly):

> [**spit and polish**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spit-and-polish) [informal]
>   ​
>   careful cleaning and shining:
>
> The car needs some spit and polish.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: The author previously says "*I believe in...a bit of gardening*" which cleverly preludes to "faith"